# Updating Textbox w/ Input After Button Clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with 2 textboxes and a button. One textbox is for the user to enter their score and the other displays their scores they entered with a space between each. The button is for the user to be able to add there scores.

Ex: 1 *hits button* 2 *hits button* 3

Now the textbox is updated with the scores that they entered: 1 2 3 is displayed.

I know I need to use a list for this so I already declared it inside my form:
`List<int> scoresArray = new List<int>();`

I'm having trouble with 2 things:
- Clearing the textbox once they hit the button incase they have more scores they want to enter
- Updating the other textbox with all of the scores they entered.

I know how to add things to a list but I'm not sure what to do if you don't know how many times the user will enter things.

Comment: Next time please post a full snippet of what you've already tried.

Comment: The way I would do this is have two counter variables.  Setup a callback so that when button one is clicked, it increments the first counter.  Likewise for the callback when button two is clicked.  I would not do any thing with a list.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, you can add additional text in the textbox instance.Text.

```
Textbox.Text += "Entered score";
```